# Django runserver seems to run two instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am working on a project where users can post and comment.
I made one app called core.
In core/views there is a file comments.py
There is a class inside it like this:

```
class CommentList(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    print("hello")

    def get(self, request: request.Request, pub_id: str) -> Response:
        pass
```

Also my core/views/__init__.py has this:

```
from .comments import *
```

Now when I run
`python3.10 manage.py runserver`,
it prints 'hello' two times.
I expect hello to be printed once.
Any possible explanation ?

Comment: Performing system checks and starting server?

Comment: @Sayse, yes it does system checks as well as the server starts

Comment: if you remove import form __init__.py it will print only once. Django Initilize all code on start so there is yours first print. then you do it again importing it to __init__.py